# why added delete keyword additional spec in typescript4.0 release spec?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript4.0

In this typescript v4.0, a new specification has been added for delete keyword.

[spec]

```
When using the delete operator in strictNullChecks, the operand must now be any, unknown, never, or be optional (in that it contains undefined in the type). 
Otherwise, use of the delete operator is an error.
```

I don't understand why this spec added.

Why can't delete specific type ?

I wonder why these specs were added.

I can turn off the "strictNullChecks" option, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Thank you.

--- edit ---
[example]

```
type UserFromDatabase = {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

type User = Omit<UserFromDatabase, "password">


const signIn = (): User => {


  const userFromDatabase: UserFromDatabase = getUserFromDatabase();

  // do something
  // compare password ...

  delete userFromDatabase.password; // error occured typescript 4.0

  const user: User = { ...userFromDatabase };

  return user;
}
```

--- edit2 ---
typescript version : v4.0 [ new spec - delete keyword allow types ]

I know that javascript's delete keyword is deleting object's property not object.

Some object key is available when important logic.

So, after doing important logic, I want to delete object key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could delete something, that means that something might not exist (especially after being deleted), so the type of that something has to allow non-existence. Consider the following example:

```
type T = {
    x: string;
}

let object: T = { x: "a" };
delete object.x;

// this is not supposed to make sense
console.log(object.x.toLowerCase());
```

In fact, the last line will throw an error in runtime. So it is the right thing to have stricter type check to prevent this kind of runtime error.

## Update

So in your case you can do:

```
delete (userFromDatabase as any).password;
const user: User = userFromDatabase;
```

Or, as Aluan Haddad pointed out, a more clever way without using `delete` is:

```
let { password, ...user } = userFromDatabase;
return user;
```

Comment: For example, consider the process of logging in.

We will get the customer's ID and password from the database.

At this time, the password is hashed, but you need to verify that the passwords match.

After that, I want to deliver the logged-in information to the user, except for the password.

Comment: So, I did delete user object's password property using delete keyword. But, it is occured error.

Comment: You could bypass it by first convert your object into `any`, if you're clear about what you're doing.

Comment: And after deleting, if you still need type checking, you could convert your result into `Omit<LoginInfo, "password">`.

Comment: Rather than a type assertion, and given the code in the question, why not just split the object up like `const {password, ...user} = userFromDatabase; return user;` and use type inference, or `Omit` as you mentioned, to handle the return type. Good answer/explanation regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) type to delete its property:

```js
type UserFromDatabase = {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

type User = Omit<UserFromDatabase, "password">

function deletePassword(user: UserFromDatabase): User {
  delete (user as Partial<UserFromDatabase>).password;
  return user;
}
```